# What are some techniques in designing around a colorful logo?

Tags: website-design, color, logo, color-theory

I usually have to make websites based around logos that are very colorful (4-5 colors). Let's say the colors of the logo is similar to the logos of Chrome, eBay, Joomla, MSN.

What are some of the techniques to designing around such logos especially those that are very vibrant / bright? (Putting them side-by-side makes the colors clash.)

One technique I know is to use plenty of white space and use the colors as 'accents'. Are there other guidelines? Should all the colors be used?

Comment: Some of the suggestions on [How do I work with a logo that has what seems like too many colors?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20272/how-do-i-work-with-a-logo-that-has-what-seems-like-too-many-colors?rq=1) might help (though this sounds like a different question as it sounds like it isn't a bad logo, just a colourful one)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the white space (room to breathe) you mentioned, I think white backgrounds (or possibly black or near white/black tones) are a must have. Logos need to be bold and a neutral tone at one extreme of the spectrum (usually white) is the best way to [accomplish maximum contrast](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19911/site-design-complementary-colors-vs-analogous-colors/19914#19914) on any combination of colors.